# Redux remote devtool also updating another computer within same LAN

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

The Android simulator works fine with Redux remote devtools at computer A. This is also the same at computer B.

However, when I open both computer A and B in the same LAN, when I do some actions at simulator at computer A, apart from updating Redux remote devtools at computer A, it also updates that at computer B! This is also the same when I do actions at computer B.

I believe, it may due to the Redux remote devtools is connecting by same local ip with the same port in both computers.

Is there any way that I can separate them?